# SQL multiple column sort not working

Tags: sql

I try to select data from a table and order rows by 2 columns. It's sorted ok by first column(likes) but for the second one not.

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE topic='$id' AND date='$date'
ORDER BY likes DESC, cpc DESC
LIMIT 4
```

I thought problems is in LIMIT, i deleted it, but is not working as well. 
What can be the problem?
Thank you

[image: It's just a part of my table, here's just the columns i am operating with]

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data that is not being sorted as you expect it.

Comment: Can you post some example data where it isn't working?

Comment: Your data shows no issues.  It first sorted by likes descending, since there are no duplicates the CPC sort didn't matter.  Perhaps you need to do CPC first then likes?  Or you need to understand how sorting works... which is in the order listed.

Comment: Yes, is sorted descending by likes but for cpc ís sorted ascending. Don't now what can be the reason.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just your brain tripping

Comment: @ValeriuMazare read the comments and my answer two times

Comment: Let's try this a different way: in order for likes and CPC to both be sorted descending in the manner you want, we would have to lose the integredity of data between the records.  Likes of 20 go with CPC of 0.  if you want likes of 20 to go with CPC 5 that would corrupt the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is OK! It first sorts by `likes` and afterwards if some data would have **the same value of `values`** then it would sort by `cpc`. But your `likes` are unique so there is no difference between:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE topic='$id' AND date='$date'
ORDER BY likes DESC, cpc DESC
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE topic='$id' AND date='$date'
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

Probably you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
  FROM content
  WHERE topic='$id' AND date='$date'
  ORDER BY likes DESC
  LIMIT 4) a
ORDER BY a.cpc DESC
```

Comment: Ook, my fault. I understood now. But if i want this:
to select 4 entries ordered by likes DESC, and then, sort these 4 by cpc ? how can i do that? thank you.

Comment: @ValeriuMazare Check now please

Answer (score 1):

It's vital to remember that all of the data in your tables are related. So field values in your CPC column directly tie to the field values in your likes column.

The results of each column do not act independent of each other (at least not the way you have written this query).

So with that concept in mind, this data is sorted correctly. Your Likes column is sorted and then the CPC is sorted based on the static Likes sort. If you had two lines of data with 20 likes and the CPC was 2 and 20, respectively, then you would see those values sorted in order based on your

```
 Order by cpc desc
```

line. But since you only have one CPC value for your Likes line of 20, that will be the value to appear. Take the same example for the next line, and the one after that and you can see that the values do in fact appear in order.