# What is the best way to group and sort data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

Hi I have the dataframe

```
df_warnings
```

which captures the warnings from a server log, and looks like the below (first 3 rows shown):

```
URI code    method  tid type
date                    
2017-06-20  URI: /app/faces/pages/oversight/Oversight.jspx  ADFC-64001  oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' WARNING
2017-06-20  URI: /app/faces/pages/oversight/Oversight.jspx  ADFC-64001  oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' WARNING
2017-06-20  URI: /app/faces/pages/oversight/Oversight.jspx  ADFC-64001  oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' WARNING
```

The 'code' & 'method' columns are strings. What I would like to do is :

- group the 'method' values by the 'code' value (i.e. I would like to see the methods and the counts of those methods against each code)
- group the counts of each method within each code group in descending order
- order the groups (codes) in descending order
- only show the top 3 methods & counts in each code group

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: I have tried

```
df_warnings['method'].groupby(df_warnings['code']).value_counts()
```

Which gives me the methods & method counts binned by code; however it doesnt give me the top 3 methods & methods counts in each code bin, and code bins are not ordered in descending order of total count in the bin

EDIT2: output I would like

```html
code    method    count
code1   A         100
        B         50
        C         5
        D         2
code2   A         50
        B         10
code3   C         50
        D         5
```

In the above code1 code2 and code3 are sorted in terms of total count in each (157, 60 and 55 respectively) and then the methods & counts are sorted within each group

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for the question see edit

Comment: Thanks @jezrael; I only need the top 3 methods & counts for each code group; and I want code groups to be sorted by total count in them and counts within the groups to also be sorted. I don't need a data frame for each step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for count and then [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
d = {'method': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 'code': ['code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

```
print (df.head())
    code method
0  code1      C
1  code1      C
2  code1      C
3  code1      C
4  code1      C


df2 = df.groupby(['code'])['method'].value_counts()
print (df2)
code   method
code1  C         100
       A          50
       B           5
       D           2
code2  C          50
       A          10
code3  C          50
       D           5
Name: method, dtype: int64

df2 = df.groupby(['code'])['method'].value_counts().sort_index()
print (df2)
code   method
code1  A          50
       B           5
       C         100
       D           2
code2  A          10
       C          50
code3  C          50
       D           5
Name: method, dtype: int64
```

---

```
#in real data change 2 to 3
df2 = df2.groupby(level='code',group_keys=False ).nlargest(2)
print (df2)
code   method
code1  C         100
       A          50
code2  C          50
       A          10
code3  C          50
       D           5
Name: method, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

I try a bit explain `sort_values` by samples (I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22568028/2901002) answer it explain better, although it is not pandas.):

```
d = {'method': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 'code': ['code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code1', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code2', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3', 'code3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#print (df.head())
```

---

```
df3 = df.groupby(['code'])['method'].value_counts().reset_index(name='vals')
#some random shuffle of rows
a = df3.index.values
np.random.seed(88)
np.random.shuffle(a)
df3 = df3.reindex(a).sort_index()
print (df3)
    code method  vals
0  code3      D     5
1  code2      A    10
2  code2      C    50
3  code1      A    50
4  code1      C   100
5  code1      B     5
6  code1      D     2
7  code3      C    50

print (df3.sort_values(['code']))
    code method  vals
3  code1      A    50
4  code1      C   100
5  code1      B     5
6  code1      D     2
1  code2      A    10
2  code2      C    50
0  code3      D     5
7  code3      C    50

print (df3.sort_values(['method']))
    code method  vals
1  code2      A    10
3  code1      A    50
5  code1      B     5
2  code2      C    50
4  code1      C   100
7  code3      C    50
0  code3      D     5
6  code1      D     2

print (df3.sort_values(['vals'], ascending=False))
    code method  vals
4  code1      C   100
2  code2      C    50
3  code1      A    50
7  code3      C    50
1  code2      A    10
0  code3      D     5
5  code1      B     5
6  code1      D     2

#if sorting by multiples columns it sort all columns separately:
#so first sort all values in df by first column, then sort by second and last by 3. col
print (df3.sort_values(['code','method']))
    code method  vals
3  code1      A    50
5  code1      B     5
4  code1      C   100
6  code1      D     2
1  code2      A    10
2  code2      C    50
7  code3      C    50
0  code3      D     5

print (df3.sort_values(['code','vals'], ascending=[True, False]))
    code method  vals
4  code1      C   100
3  code1      A    50
5  code1      B     5
6  code1      D     2
2  code2      C    50
1  code2      A    10
7  code3      C    50
0  code3      D     5

print (df3.sort_values(['method', 'vals'], ascending=[True, False]))
    code method  vals
3  code1      A    50
1  code2      A    10
5  code1      B     5
4  code1      C   100
2  code2      C    50
7  code3      C    50
0  code3      D     5
6  code1      D     2

print (df3.sort_values(['vals', 'method'], ascending=[False, True]))
    code method  vals
4  code1      C   100
3  code1      A    50
2  code2      C    50
7  code3      C    50
1  code2      A    10
5  code1      B     5
0  code3      D     5
6  code1      D     2

print (df3.sort_values(['vals', 'method', 'code'], ascending=[True, False, False]))
    code method  vals
6  code1      D     2
0  code3      D     5
5  code1      B     5
1  code2      A    10
7  code3      C    50
2  code2      C    50
3  code1      A    50
4  code1      C   100

print (df3.sort_values(['code', 'method', 'vals'], ascending=[True, False, True]))
    code method  vals
6  code1      D     2
4  code1      C   100
5  code1      B     5
3  code1      A    50
2  code2      C    50
1  code2      A    10
0  code3      D     5
7  code3      C    50
```

Comment: thanks for this, almost works - what this doesn't do unfortunately is sort the bins themselves by the total count in the bin; it does sort the items in the bins by count; with your answer the second largest code bin appears 4th in the bin list not 2nd

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Comment: the format is exactly as you have it, but I would like for the code groups themselves ordered by the largest group to the smallest group also (I switched the method & code in you answer since I need codes grouped by methods)

Comment: I dont understand, sorry.

Comment: see edit above - thanks for clarifying and let me know whether it makes sense

Comment: do you need for sorted output dataframe with 3 columns?

Comment: I dont need a dataframe just sorted groups exactly as you have shown in your answer; your new answer still doesnt give me the groups sorted in count order :-/; in the real data code 'OWS-00179' is 2nd largest but appears as the 4th group in the list when I follow your answer

Comment: Yes, but then there is problem - do you need sort by `method` or by numbers? Because together it is impossible.

Comment: i add code for sort `code` with `method`, but then values are not sorted, because impossible.

Comment: See second EDIT in my answer - it is sorted by 'code' first (by total count in each group) and then the 'methods' in each code are also sorted by count

Comment: Unfortunately it is ideal, but in real no. Because my data are different and no first sorted value in group is first sorted value in `code` :( Sorry.

Comment: :( thanks for your effort; just thinking if its easier to put the output into a dataframe and then do the hierarchical sort (ie sort by code, then sort by method) do let me know.

Comment: yes, exactly [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) do it. First sort by `method` and then by `code`. It works nice, because values in `method` are duplicated. I add some code for better explanation.

Comment: Thanks and please do

Comment: Sorry, give me a sec.

Comment: I add many samples. I hope it help you. good luck! (and now I am going home ;))

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It has helped me.